# Javascript form submission

Tags: javascript, forms, sugarcrm

I have a form that posts its data to Sugar CRM. The data is being successfully submited in Firefox but not redirecting correctly. In Chrome the data is not being submitted but is redirecting correctly.

```
<form method="POST" class="brochurelead webtoleadform" name="WebToLeadForm" id="WebToLeadForm">    
  <fieldset>
    <label for="firstname">First name*:</label>
    <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" />
  <br />
    <label for="lastname">Last name*:</label>
    <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" />
  <br />
    <label for="phone_work">Primary phone*:</label>
    <input type="text" name="phone_work" id="phone_work" onchange="validateHuman();"/>
  <br />
  <label for="email">Email*:</label>
  <input type="text" name="email1" id="email1" onchange="validateEmailAdd();" />
  <span style="padding-left:268px"><input type="submit" value="Download" name="Submit" class="button" onclick="submit_form();" />
</fieldset1>

  <input type="hidden" name="lead_source" id="lead_source" value="Brochure Download" />
  <input type="hidden" name="user" id="user" value="lead_capture_form" />
  <input type="hidden" value="dbce057c" name="campaign_id" id="campaign_id" />
  <input type="hidden" value="http://www.somewebsite.com/somearticle" name="redirect" id="redirect" />
  <input type="hidden" value="blahblah" name="assigned_user_id" id="assigned_user_id" />
  <input type="hidden" value="first_name;last_name;phone_work;email1;" name="req_id" id="req_id" />
  <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $article->category; ?>" name="area_of_interest_c" id="area_of_interest_c">
  <input type="hidden" name="probability_c" id="probability_c" value="1" />
  <input type="hidden" id="human" name="human" value="0">
</form>
```

This is my javascript for handling the form:

```
function submit_form(){
    if(typeof(validateCaptchaAndSubmit)!='undefined'){
        validateCaptchaAndSubmit();
    }else{
        check_webtolead_fields();
    }
}

function check_webtolead_fields(){
    if(document.getElementById('req_id') != null){
        var reqs=document.getElementById('req_id').value;
        reqs = reqs.substring(0,reqs.lastIndexOf(';'));
        var req_fields = new Array();
        var req_fields = reqs.split(';');
        nbr_fields = req_fields.length;
        var req = true;
        for(var i=0;i<nbr_fields;i++){
            if(document.getElementById(req_fields[i]).value.length <=0 || document.getElementById(req_fields[i]).value==0){
                req = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(req && document.getElementById('human').value == '50'){
            document.WebToLeadForm.action = "http://crm.somewebsite.com/index.php?entryPoint=WebToLeadCapture";
            document.WebToLeadForm.submit();
            window.location = document.getElementById('redirect').value;
            return true;
        }
        else{
            alert('Please provide all the required fields');
            return false;
        }
        return false
    }
    else{
        document.WebToLeadForm.action = "http://crm.somewebsite.com/index.php?entryPoint=WebToLeadCapture";
        document.WebToLeadForm.submit();
        window.location = document.getElementById('redirect').value;
    }
}

function validateEmailAdd(){
    if(document.getElementById('email1').value.length >0) {
        if(document.getElementById('email1').value.match(/^\w+(['\.\-\+]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,})+$/) == null){
            alert('Not a valid email address');
        }
    }
}

function validateHuman(){
    document.getElementById('human').value = "50";
}
```

Comment: `not being sumbitted`: any errors or something ?

Comment: No errors. The form submits it data correctly on firefox but does not redirect back instead it just sticks on this url `index.php?entryPoint=WebToLeadCapture` on Chrome it redirects to the correct URL but does not submit the data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are submitting a form and trying to set the page's location at the same time. That is not going to happen. It is a race condition!

Either you will have to submit the form with Ajax can on the response you redirect OR you need the serverside to actually do the redirection!

Comment: You're right! This line `window.location = document.getElementById('redirect').value;` is never neede because this line `<input type="hidden" value="http://www.somewebsite.com/somearticle" name="redirect" id="redirect" />` is passed to be dealt with server side. Thanks!